# how to conduct mathematical operations using numerical characteristics attached to vertices

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Given a directed graph `g`:

```
Clear[g, conn];
SeedRandom[311];
g = RandomGraph[{6, 9}, DirectedEdges -> True]
conn = ConnectedComponents[g]
conn[[4]]
```

I want to attach a set of characteristics to each vertex in the graph. Define vertex characteristics as:

```
 v1->{2,4,7};
 v2->{1,4,1};
 v3->{2,4,1};
 v4->{0,4,1};
 v5->{6,1,7};
 v6->{4,0,1};
```

Find strongly connected components (SCCs) and choose the largest SCC, with vertices `{v2, v3, v4}`. Then, find the sum of the `first` characteristic of these vertices. This should give me `1+2+0 = 3`. Or find the sum of the `third` characteristic of the same vertices: `1+1+1=3`.

Any suggestions to improve the above `code`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vprops = {{2, 4, 7}, {1, 4, 1}, {2, 4, 1}, {0, 4, 1}, {6, 1, 7}, {4, 0, 1}};

rules = Thread[VertexList[g] -> vprops];
```

You can use `rules` with `ReplaceAll`:

```
conn[[4]] /. rules
```

> {{1, 4, 1}, {2, 4, 1}, {0, 4, 1}}

```
 %[[All, 1]]
```

> {1, 2, 0}

```
Total @ %
```

> 3

Alternatively, construct an `Association` using `VertexList[g]` and `vprops`:

```
assoc = AssociationThread[VertexList[g], vprops]
```

> <|1 -> {2, 4, 7}, 2 -> {1, 4, 1}, 3 -> {2, 4, 1}, 4 -> {0, 4, 1}, 
>    5 -> {6, 1, 7}, 6 -> {4, 0, 1}|>

```
Total @ Query[conn[[4]], First] @ assoc
```

> 3

You can also attach `rules` as a custom property to `g`:

```
g2 = SetProperty[g, "customvertexProperty" -> rules];

conn[[4]] /. PropertyValue[g2, "customvertexProperty"]
```

> {{1, 4, 1}, {2, 4, 1}, {0, 4, 1}}

**Update:** To get the largest component:

```
conn[[Ordering[Length /@ conn, -1]]]
```

> {{2, 3, 4}}

```
conn[[OrderingBy[conn, Length, -1]]]
```

> {{2, 3, 4}}

```
MaximalBy[Length] @ conn
```

> {{2, 3, 4}}

```
Last @ Sort @ conn
```

> {2, 3, 4}

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and for showing the alternative ways of answering the question. In your answer, the question of finding the largest (in terms of the number of vertices) connected component is somehow missing. Is there a specific command to find the largest SCC?

Comment: @Tugrul, added several methods to get the largest connected component.